# Founded div overflow anchor element number of open jobs

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, design

I've noticed that div `#company-profile > [data-company-section="company-info"] > ul > li.founded` overflow with `#jobsanchor`.

Click to the img below to view demo.
[image]

Comment: Please focus on the bug, don't try to analyse it technically with programming stuff, it's just making it confusing. Link to the page where it happens, add what browser you're using etc. If you then have an idea how to fix it and thus help the team fix it faster great, add it, but don't make it the whole bug report.

Comment: Looks clear to me - we got a styling problem on the company page. This report is fine.

Comment: @Tim I have updated the OP's image with red circle on overlap

Comment: @Tim Nope, it's not a browser issue.

Comment: @HackerKarma No i mean not seeing the image.

Answer (score 3):

Whoa, that looks pretty gnarly. Fix will be going out soon. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like UI has been tweaked and 'open jobs' link is now moved next to URL. Loos good, no overlap issue there.